# Passing a bytes32 as a parameter from web3, returns invalid opcode

Tags: web3js

When I deploy the solidity contract and make the tests with mocha, the result of a function that receives a bytes32 parameter works fine. But, when I make the same with web3 in order to make the process in the UI, always I obtain an invalid opcode (an error). I don't know what I am doing wrong, in advance any clarification is welcome.

**Here my function in solidity contract (works fine in remix, for example):**

```
struct EntityStruct {
  address person;
  address originPath;
  address destinationPath;
  uint distance;
  bool isEntity;
}

mapping (bytes32 => EntityStruct) public entityStructData;  

function hashTheID(bytes32 stringToHash) constant public returns(bytes32 stringHashed)
{
   // This function returns a valid data. This function never throws error
   return keccak256(stringToHash);
}

function setEntityData(address originPath, address destinationPath, uint distance, bytes32 stringHashed) public payable returns (bool success)
{
  require(originPath != address(0x0));
  require(destinationPath != address(0x0));

  entityStructData[stringHashed].person = msg.sender;
  entityStructData[stringHashed].originPath = originPath;
  entityStructData[stringHashed].destinationPath = destinationPath;
  entityStructData[stringHashed].distance = distance;
  entityStructData[stringHashed].isEntity = true;

  // I have the declaration of this event in other part of the contract
  LogPersonSetted(msg.sender, originPath, destinationPath, distance);
  return true;
}

function getIfEntityData(bytes32 stringToHash) constant public returns (bool isEntity)
{
  // The idea is that the user gives the string without the hash,
  // but this function always fails when I call with web3
  bytes32 stringHashed = hashTheID(stringToHash);
  return (entityStructData[stringHashed].isEntity);
}
```

**Here is the call from web3 using react:**

I make all the calls to the contract with this structure, so I am sure that the data like 'contractInstance' is correctos. And I pass the parameter the same as the contract function 'hashTheID' returns to me, This doesn't work.

```
contractInstance.getIfEntityData(stringToHash, { from: entity } )
  .then((success) => {
    console.log(success);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: Are you sure this is your exact code? A missing semicolon means the code you shared won't compile.

Comment: Also, what's `contractInstance`? Is this web3.js 0.2.0x? 1.0.0? Or maybe truffle?

Comment: I have put the missing semicolon, but that is not the reason. 'contractInstance' is web3.js 1.0.0

Comment: Then if it's web3 1.0.0 you are not using the correct syntax for methods call. Take a look at the 1.0.0 doc: http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call

Comment: In web3.js 1.0.0, you would write something like `contractInstance.methods.getIfEntityData(web3.utils.toHex("test")).call().then(console.log)`. The code you wrote would produce an error.

Comment: The thing is that I want to pass a clear parameter, I mean, without the method "web3.utils.toHex("test")', because I need that that hashing occurs inside the contract not from the outside. That is because I have a method named 'hashTheID' inside the contract, and I use 'keccak256'. If I use your recommendation (the one that I appreciate so much, and thank you a lot), I am sending other string and it crashes.

Comment: My issue is similar to this one. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/31884/invalid-op-code-passing-bytes32-array-to-a-contract-method-called-from-another. So, the problem is with testrpc?